# Python: Transform and superimpose sets of points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, transform

Is there a python package, (maybe in numpy) to transform and superimpose one set of points on another(both in 3D) defined by matrices and perform a least squares fit?

Comment: Do you mean a rigid transformation? You could consider either an affine or a more general homography.

Comment: Does your superimposition imply scaling, rotation and translation or just rotation?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye No scaling. Only rotation and translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *ordered* 3D point clouds, there are several repositories which do rigid-body superpositions in matlab, python, and C++:

https://github.com/nghiaho12/rigid_transform_3D

https://github.com/jewettaij/superpose3d

https://github.com/jewettaij/superpose3d_cpp

(The last two repositories can handle rescaling/magnification).

If you want to allow other kinds of (linear) transformations, (or if you have point clouds in higher dimensions) then scroll down to the bottom of this blog where the user-comments are located:

http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671

I also assume that the point clouds are ordered.  (In other words, I assume that you know which pairs of points from either cloud correspond to each other.)  If that is not the case, but if the point clouds correspond to biomolecules (proteins, RNA), then you can usually assume that the point clouds preserve order but contain gaps (as would be the case if they evolved from a common ancestor).  In that case you should look for protein structure alignment algorithms.  *(Shameless plug: I wrote one called "minrms", but there are many others.)*  But if you genuinely *don't know anything about the order of the points*, then the problem is a very hard combinatorial problem indeed.  In that case, I suspect the best solutions will be probabilistic algorithms, and you will probably have to search the literature to find an algorithm that suites your specific needs.

Cheers

-a

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using OpenCV for a 2D transformation:

```
cv2.estimateRigidTransform(
        src_points,
        dst_points,
        fullAffine=False)
```

Returns a 3x2 [affine matrix](http://nghiaho.com/?p=2208).

---

For arbitrary dimensions, there's probably a relevant function in the Point Cloud Library.